# How to set up a Google Analytics experiment in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-analytics, single-page-application

I set up Google Analytics tracking in meteor using the okgrow:analytics package. It works and I get the real time view of pages and events correctly. I want to run an A/B test to compare one of the features of my app. However, I ran into a few problems, mostly stemming from the fact that Meteor creates a SPA:

Google Analytics asks me to insert a script to track the experiment right after the opening head tag on the page I am trying to test. I can do that, but either I will have to put it on the head which is used among all the pages or inject dynamically which causes an error.

It seems that the Google Analytics script is not changing the page correctly. This is probably related to the fact that I can't insert the script into the head correctly, but I was thinking it might also be because it is a single page app and it seems like the script expects a more traditional website.

Also please note that I am using Flow Router.

I have searched without any luck. Does anyone know how to set this up correctly? Any suggestions or ideas would also be welcome.

Comment: You're going to have to use the Google [Content Experiments JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/experiments#cxjs). Their docs give good insight into that.

Comment: Hey @MichelFloyd, that is what I ended up doing, though I found out about it in a pretty roundabout way, if you post your comment as an answer and maybe flesh it out, I will accept it as the answer to this question